# why use a mdf if using a sqlproj in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mdf, sqlproj

I set up a MVC 4 project and created a sqlproj to store all my database objects. I can publish it to sql express and then to Azure just fine. I know there is a .mdf file for an actual database that gets placed into the app_data folder in my solution, but is this needed? At this point in my project or if I'm thinking long term, what are the advantages/benefits of creating a .mdf and using it? Should I use both in my solution?

Comment: Are you storing data in both?

Comment: right now I don't have any .mdf.